# Model Builder ArcGIS - Export topology errors (Iteration Tool)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, export, topology, iteration

I was wondering if there’s any option to iterate `export topology errors` in ArcGIS model builder. My GDB Topology errors has all topologies within the same Topology dataset but model builder seems not have the option to go throughout the same topology dataset and export the errors (line, point and polygon) for each topology file. Here the structure of the topology errors GDB:

[image]

My idea is iterate each topology file (e.g. T_RailwaysAlignment3DCentreline_Ln) and export them with same name (e.g. T_RailwaysAlignment3DCentreline_Ln_Line).

The following screenshot shows the test model prepared for this purpose:

[image]

`Iteration Tool – Iterate Dataset`

[image]

`Export Topology Lines`

[image]

Any ideas how export the topology errors (within the same topo dataset) using Model Builder? (Python ideas more than welcomed too)